# Python - make file and then make python move into it

Tags: python, file, move

I currently don't work with GUI of any sort since im pretty new, and still learning python itself.

I have a lot of text files with settings for my program that I can adjust. I like it better this way, since I do not always have to enter them whenever I run my program.

In the folder where I have my currently python code folder, I have around 10 text files. How can I create a file 'settings', move all of my text files into it, and then make python change directory into that directory?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
         os.system("mv \""+file+"\" \"./settings/"+file+"\"")
         os.system("cd settings")
```

Comment: You also need to add a final `os.chdir()` into that folder.

Comment: Miqro asked "and then make python cd into that directory"